# Multiple character delimiter in java

Tags: java

Given the following input

```
s = "//[***]\n1***2***3"
```

I need to split the part after "\n" around the sequence of characters inside the square brackets, following the syntax below:

```
"//[delimiter]\n"
```

First, I need to check if the string in input matches the syntax, i wrote it this way:

```
if(s.matches("[//[.+].+]")){
        String delimiter = s.substring(3, s.indexOf(']'));
        String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf(']')+3); //the part after \n which I need to split
        String[] nums = s1.split("[delimiter]");
    }
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 4
[,
[]
```

Can you help me with the right regex syntax?

Comment: You need to escape the `[` and `]`, as square brackets have special meaning in regex: [character classes](https://regular-expressions.mobi/charclass.html?wlr=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `"[delimiter]"` is a pure literal string. It doesn't evaluate the value of the variable `delimiter`. So that doesn't make much sense.

Second, String.split() expects a regexp as argument, but you want to pass a literal delimiter. So you need to quote your delimiter:

```
String[] nums = s1.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter));
```

Also,

```
s.substring(s.indexOf(']') + 3);
```

should be

```
s.substring(s.indexOf(']') + 2);
```

`\n` is a single character, not two.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the square bracket. Also, a more robust way to extract the delimiter would be using a group:

```
String input = "//[@]\\n1@2@3";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("//\\[(.+?)]\\\\n");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String delimiter = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Groups are defined within parantheses (so in this case, the group is `(.+?)`) and you can have multiple groups, and then use the `group(i)` to get the value of the i-th group.

Comment: you don't need to escape the closing bracket, because there's no character class in the regex. (the opening bracket does not define a character class as this one is escaped)